# Mysql last_value window function on a datetime column

Tags: mysql, datetime, window-functions, partition

Below is the data set I am working with:

```
customer_id,        event_date,             status,         credit_limit
1,                  2019-1-1,                   C,                  1000
1,                  2019-1-5,                   F,                  1000
1,                  2019-3-10,             [NULL],                  1000
1,                  2019-3-10,              [NULL],                 1000
1,                  2019-8-27,                  L,                  1000
2,                  2019-1-1,                   L,                  2000
2,                  2019-1-5,               [NULL],                 2500
2,                  2019-3-10,              [NULL],                 2500
3,                  2019-1-1,                   S,                  5000
3,                  2019-1-5,               [NULL],                 6000
3,                  2019-3-10,                  B,                  5000
4,                  2019-3-10,                  B,                  10000
```

I am trying to solve for the following:

```
For each customer_id, show account status at month end for the year 2019
```

I have tried using windows function last_value(), but it does not give me the latest date in a month. Here is my query:

```
with cte1 as 
(select customer_id, status, 
event_date,
last_value(date_format(event_date, '%Y-%m-%d')) over ( partition by customer_id, event_date
order by event_date) as l_v
from cust_acct ca 
where event_date between "2019-01-01 00:00:00" and "2019-12-31 11:59:59")
select * from cte1
```

It returns:

```
Customer_id,    Status,         Event_date,                 L_v
1,          C,          2019-01-01 00:00:00,            2019-01-01
1,          F,          2019-01-05 00:00:00,            2019-01-05
1,      [NULL],         2019-03-10 00:00:00,            2019-03-10
1,      [NULL],         2019-03-10 00:00:00,            2019-03-10
1,          L,          2019-08-27 00:00:00,            2019-08-27
2,          L,          2019-01-01 00:00:00,            2019-01-01
2,      [NULL],         2019-01-05 00:00:00,            2019-01-05
2,      [NULL],         2019-03-10 00:00:00,            2019-03-10
3,          S,          2019-01-01 00:00:00,            2019-01-01
3,      [NULL],         2019-01-05 00:00:00,            2019-01-05
3,          B,          2019-03-10 00:00:00,            2019-03-10
4,          B,          2019-03-10 00:00:00,            2019-03-10
```

Customer_id 1, for month 2019-01, should have a last_value of '2019-01-05' in the column l_v. Why is the query showing both dates in january in column l_v?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`LAST_VALUE()` is not the proper window function in this case.
It can be used only if you extend the window:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT customer_id, status, event_date,
  LAST_VALUE(DATE(event_date)) OVER ( 
    PARTITION BY customer_id, DATE_FORMAT(event_date, '%Y-%m')
    ORDER BY event_date 
    ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND UNBOUNDED FOLLOWING
  ) AS l_v
  FROM cust_acct ca 
  WHERE event_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 11:59:59'
)
SELECT * FROM cte1;
```

You should use `FIRST_VALUE()`:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT customer_id, status, event_date,
  FIRST_VALUE(DATE(event_date)) OVER ( 
    PARTITION BY customer_id, DATE_FORMAT(event_date, '%Y-%m')
    ORDER BY event_date DESC
  ) AS l_v
  FROM cust_acct ca 
  WHERE event_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 11:59:59'
)
SELECT * FROM cte1;
```

or better `MAX()`:

```
WITH cte1 AS (
  SELECT customer_id, status, event_date,
  MAX(DATE(event_date)) OVER ( 
    PARTITION BY customer_id, DATE_FORMAT(event_date, '%Y-%m')
  ) AS l_v
  FROM cust_acct ca 
  WHERE event_date BETWEEN '2019-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2019-12-31 11:59:59'
)
SELECT * FROM cte1;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=8fb866a9b6450fdc91bd7f02a5f90207).

Comment: Why is `LAST_VALUE()` wrong? And doesn't `FIRST_VALUE()` become right only because you reversed the order?

Comment: Thanks! Both work, but can you explain why last_value is not the right function?

Comment: LAST_VALUE() is not the opposite of FIRST_VALUE(). Check this example in the documentation: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_first-value